# How do I message another user here?

Tags: discussion

I'm new here and would like to ask the user of this question [Running caffe gives error Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (30 vs. 0) unknown error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838289/running-caffe-gives-error-check-failed-error-cudasuccess-30-vs-0-unknown) if they have checked this link http://docs.roguewave.com/totalview/8.14.1/html/index.html#page/User_Guides/totalviewug-about-cuda.31.4.html because it looks like there might be some compatibility issues here.

vera

Comment: I was on the chat when this meta post arrived so I got your message.

Comment: @Thijser Glad you got message or I was going to comment on your question ;)

Answer (score 8):

Get 50 reputation (writing a couple of good answers, suggesting a load of edits, asking some really interesting questions, etc) and then you can comment. This barrier —annoying as it is— is to help prevent spam as well as other things that shouldn't be comments that are more likely to come from brand new users.

If they were active on Chat, that might be another route but you also need at least 20 rep for that.

But they're not the only ways to find somebody.

- They have a profile on this site. Click the avatar. They might have contact information listed. It might seem weird but if it's in there, it's fair game. That's them saying how they *want* to be contacted.
- Is their username unique? Can you find instances of that elsewhere on the internet?
- You could even crank up the creep factor to 11 and throw their avatar through [Google Images](https://images.google.com/) to find them in other places.
- Hack PRISM (the US surveillance program), find logs of traffic that could have only been from them (eg the post URL for that question), hack their ISP to get their billing info and give them a phone call.

But ideally, this is exactly the sort of question that's best for a comment.
Earning 50 rep is fairly easy and involves less prison time than some of these options.

Comment: Not in a rude manner, but I would add the phrase "[**I use Google before asking dumb questions**](http://www.justfuckinggoogleit.com/)... Just in case, saying... :D

Comment: @muru [Yup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257816/demystifying-chat-reputation-requirements)

Comment: "Hack PRISM (the US surveillance program), find logs of traffic that could have only been from them (eg the post URL for that question), hack their ISP to get their billing info and give them a phone call." Well, that was a good one! :-))

Answer (score -2):

> How do I message another user here?

- Just add a comment to that question mentioning `@Thijser` in the comment.
  The user will get notified.

> I need 50 reputation to make a comment there. I only have 1

- In that case you can add an answer to that question (Which is suppose to be deleted saying that 'This must be an comment not an answer'). But the user will get notified.

Comment: I need 50 karma to make a comment there. I only have 1.

Comment: In that case i might help you

Comment: Comment here what you want to ask that user

Comment: I would like to ask him if he has looked at the link I provided. It states the driver versions and shows that his driver belong to cuda 6.5.

Comment: @veranedi: Just as a side note, it's called "reputation" or "rep" her, not karma, that's LaunchPad and maybe some other sites.

Comment: @veranedi Thijser got your message

Comment: @veranedi also note that this comment may also be an answer if slightly more detailed open, given that I put a 50 bounty on this question you would be able to post comments afterwards.