# How to chat with another user?

Tags: support, chat, privileges

With 20 reputation you gains the chat privilege, [as described here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16282/689894), but I couldn't find this option in a user profile.

Where should I look for it?

Comment: " but I couldn't find this option in a user profile."  the chat link is in the top right, in the little stack exchange hamburger "community's" menu or  here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=askubuntu.com

Comment: Ooow, rigth, I wouldn't look there! Thanks @MarkKirby

Comment: If you can register it as a comment, it is the right answer to me

Comment: No worries, glad to help, I upgraded the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't find the chat links in user profiles, it is located in the top right on the black bar, in the little stack exchange hamburger "community" menu, it can be a bit hard to find.

[image]

It is also located on the footer of every page

[image]

Here is a direct link too, just for completeness

https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=askubuntu.com